# Buffering a Digital Signature/Verifcation Very Large Files Java

Tags: java, digital-signature, digital-certificate

Alright, so i have checked in a lot of places and still cannot find an answer. So I want to verify a file piece by piece instead of loading it all into memory. I know I can use a bufferedreader to update a signature piece by piece, but that is not what I want. I want to buffer in part of the data and then use the signature and the certificate to verify that part of the data and then repeat until the entire file is verified that way I am only loading a little bit of the file into memory each time. If I have a 1GB file i cannot load it into memory efficently to sign/verify the file.

Comment: Are you trying to develop your own signature scheme where you sign and verify chunks of the file, or are you trying to verify chunks of the file against a given whole-file signature? The former is possible, the latter is not. Regardless, you do not need to load the whole file in to memory to verify the signature of the whole thing. You read a bit at a time, feed it into a hashing function, and finalize the hash after you have read the whole file.

Comment: I thought about trying the first way, but then I would end up with a bunch of different signatures which might not save much space in the end. So with the latter, can you show me the code snippet? Is it just using a buffered reader and updating a signature verifier with the bytes from the file. Then once the whole file is read then verify it all? So the java signature update function hashes the input?

Comment: [Here's an example](http://www.javacreed.com/how-to-generate-sha1-hash-value-of-file/). It's not precisely what you need but it should show you the principles.

Comment: While(buffer is available) {length=buffer.read(bytebuffer) , signature.update(bytebuffer,0,length)} signature.verify(signaturebytes) does that not load the entire file into memory? It's just pseudo code because I'm not at my computer but I thought by doing that it would end up putting the entire contents of the file in memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A signature consists of a hashing operation (e.g. SHA-256), followed by a padding scheme (e.g. PSS), followed by a one way function (e.g. modular exponentiation with the private key for RSA).

Now a hash is always over the entire amount of data, and cannot be divided. The hash is usually calculated during one of the [`Signature.update`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html#update(byte)) methods, which already provide streaming support. The padding and one way function are performed during one of the [`sign`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html#sign()) or [`verify`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html#verify(byte%5B%5D)) methods.

So with just this construction you **cannot** perform a partial verification of the data.

---

One method of performing a partial verification of data is the following:

1. create a new structure containing (SHA-256) hashes over fragments of data;
2. sign the above structure with the signature, and add the signature to the structure;
3. instead of the signature, prepend the new structure to the data.

Now when reading the data:

1. First read and verify the entire structure using the signature;
2. Read any of the given fragments, and verify against the hash in the structure.

And presto.

Comment: Hope you didn't spend that long debugging the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like some confusion about how a file that is digitally signed is verified.

The trick is that, to be extremely precise, files themselves are not signed. Rather, the hash value that represents the file is signed. The hash value should be created using a [SHA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) hashing algorithm.

So the only operation that involves the entire file is the process of creating the hash value for the file. One of the SHA-2 variants is usually used.

So the real issue is to calculate the SHA-2 hash as a stream operation. That's the real question that you need to solve.

Once you have the hash value of the file, you need to do the other aspects of validating the digital signature. -- But none of them involve the file as a whole.